# How to run one function and then another function within the main()

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

So I am just learning Python and am working on an online exercises to get use to the language and software itself. Right now I am working on making one function (`getData()`) run and then the results from that function to run into another function (`getStats()`) that is all with a `main()`. Each one works individually but I am having a problem with the `main()`. I can get my first `getData()` to run and make my list but I can't get that list to run directly into `getStats()`. It actually runs the `getData()` again and then comes back with an error message when I put in an input . Does anyone have any suggestions for me to not get that error message and then to actually run my `getStats()`?

```
def getData():
    import math
    pop = []
    while True:
        user = raw_input("Please enter a population number (-1 to quit): ") 
        pop.append(user)
        if user == '-1':
            break
        if user <= '0':
            print "Population not valid, please input a value higher then 0"
    new_pop = map(int, pop)
    pop2 = filter(lambda x:x >=1, new_pop)
    print "Your population list is: ", pop2
    return
def getStats():
    i = ""
    asc = sorted(i) 
    print "The collected data in the asecending order", asc 
    dec = sorted(i, reverse = True)
    print "The collected data in the descending order", dec 
    maxi = max(i)
    print "The maximum of the collected data is", maxi 
    mini = min(i)
    print "The minimum of the collected data is",mini 
    def getMean(i):
        aver = round(sum(i), 2)/round(len(i), 2)
        print "The average of the collected data is %.2f" % aver 
    getMean(i)
    def getStdev(i):
        aver = sum(i)/len(i)
        var = sum(pow(user-aver,2) for user in i)/len(i)
        stdev = math.sqrt(var)
        print "The standard deviation of the collected data is %.2f" % stdev 
    return
def main():
    getData()
    getStats(getData())
main()
```

Comment: Please add the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks to the question by clicking the [edit] link. Please add sample input, expected output, and your actual output as well. Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The variables inside each function cannot be accessed by other functions variable/function [scope](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Variables_and_Scope.html).
One way to use them is to have the function return those values. Here is a simplified example:

```
def get_data():
    data = raw_input('Ask for data')
    return data

def get_stats(data):
   sorted_data = sorted(data)
   print 'Sorted:', sorted_data

data =  get_data() # get_data will point 'data' to the value returned
get_stats(data)    # call get_stats, and pass 'data' as an argument
```

Some other thoughts:

- You don't really need the main() function. It's not doing anything.
  What is  more common, is adding a conditional statement to only run this if you are running the file itself, but not when it's imported as a module:

  `if __name__ == '__main__':
      data =  get_data()
      get_stats(data)`
- Check out [PEP 008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

  Usually your imports should be at the beginning of the file ([Imports](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports))

  Function names are [camel_case](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names)